# "specified procedure could not be found" with Lua5.1 LuaSockets Win 64bit C++

Tags: visual-c++, luasocket, zerobrane, lua-5.1

I'm trying to make ZBS work in Windows, with both Lua 5.1 and luasockets compiled as 64bit C++ sources.  I'm getting the following error:

> error loading module 'socket.core' from file 'socket\core.dll':   The
>   specified procedure could not be found.

Any thoughts or hint on that?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you are loading 32bit luasocket libraries. To make it work, modify `package.cpath` in your script/application to reference the location for 64bit luasocket libraries first and have that modification before `require('mobdebug').start()` call. See [this ticket](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/756) for a recent discussion and [details](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/756#issuecomment-293645521).